# Gradient computation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, differentiation

I am using Tensorflow v1.14 for creating networks and training them. Everything works fine and I don't have any problem with code. I use the function `tf.reduce_min()` in my loss function. For the gradients to flow, it is essential that the loss function is differentiable. But a `min` operator is not differentiable as such. This [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/21882/79728), gives the necessary explanation for the `tf.reduce_min()` function but without references.

In general there are functions in Tensorflow (`tf.cond`, `tf.where`, among many more) that are inherently not differentiable by their definition. I want to know how these are made differentiable by defining "pseudo gradients" and the proper references to documentation. Thanks.